# Gson Deserializing Problem - If Type parameter is child class could not deserialize

Tags: java, generics, gson, json-deserialization

In **Master** class for the variable `Generic<Parent> generic` i am passing a Child Object in `main()`. During serializing i am getting correct output. But while deserializing Child Object is missing. Could anyone give suggesstions.

```
public class GenericSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Generic<Parent> generic = new Generic<Parent>();
        Child child = new Child();
        child.setName("I am child");
        generic.setT(child);

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        Master master = new Master();
        master.setId(2);
        master.setGeneric(generic);

        String valMaster = gson.toJson(master);
        System.out.println(valMaster);
        /*
         * Output: {"id":2,"generic":{"t":{"name":"I am child"}}}
         */

        Master master2 = gson.fromJson(valMaster, Master.class);
        String valMaster2 = gson.toJson(master2);
        System.out.println(valMaster2);
        /*
         * Child Object is missing
         * Output: {"id":2,"generic":{"t":{}}}
         */
    }

    static class Master {
        private int id;
        private Generic<Parent> generic;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public Generic<Parent> getGeneric() {
            return generic;
        }

        public void setGeneric(Generic<Parent> generic) {
            this.generic = generic;
        }

    }

    static class Generic<T> {
        T t;

        public T getT() {
            return t;
        }

        public void setT(T t) {
            this.t = t;
        }
        
    }
    static class Parent {
        private String type;

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

    }

    static class Child extends Parent {
        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

Gson tries to deserialize the generic value into `Parent`, not `Child`. Since there is `type` as `null`, you can see no data in the object deserialized which appears as `{}`. If you add `child.setType("type");` then the outputs become:

- `valMaster1`: `{"id":2,"generic":{"t":{"name":"I am child","type":"type"}}}`
- `valMaster2`: `{"id":2,"generic":{"t":{"type":"type"}}}`

However, the field `name` is *not* present in the `Parent` class but the `Child` class and Gson simply has no idea what subclass of `Parent` it is (if so) and completely ignores the value, which is a correct behavior.

**Solution**

I find basically two choices (I use all-args constructor for sake of brevity):

1. Elevate the upper-bounded generic type parameter to the `Master` class and specify the particular `Child` type at the point of deserialization using `com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken` and `java.lang.reflect.Type`:

   ```
   static class Master<T extends Parent> {
       private int id;
       private Generic<T> generic;

       /* getters, setters and all-args constructor */
   }
   ```

   ```
   Child child = new Child("I am child");
   Generic<Parent> generic = new Generic<>(child);
   Master<Parent> master = new Master<>(2, generic);

   Gson gson = new Gson();
   String valMaster = gson.toJson(master);
   System.out.println(valMaster);                           
   // {"id":2,"generic":{"t":{"name":"I am child"}}}

   Type type = new TypeToken<Master<Child>>() {}.getType();
   Master<Child> master2 = gson.fromJson(valMaster, type);
   String valMaster2 = gson.toJson(master2);
   System.out.println(valMaster2);
   // {"id":2,"generic":{"t":{"name":"I am child"}}}
   ```
2. Hardcode the particular generic type `Generic<Child>` inside the `Master` class. The deserialization gets the way easier, yet the design is less flexible:

   ```
   static class Master {
       private int id;
       private Generic<Child> generic;

       /* getters, setters and all-args constructor */
   }
   ```

   ```
   Child child = new Child("I am child");
   Generic<Child> generic = new Generic<>(child);
   Master master = new Master(2, generic);

   Gson gson = new Gson();
   String valMaster = gson.toJson(master);
   System.out.println(valMaster);
   // {"id":2,"generic":{"t":{"name":"I am child"}}}

   Master master2 = gson.fromJson(valMaster, Master.class);
   String valMaster2 = gson.toJson(master2);
   System.out.println(valMaster2);
   // {"id":2,"generic":{"t":{"name":"I am child"}}}
   ```

Comment: I do believe that the OP is asking for the perfect round-trip serialization/deserialization, and not hardcoding child classes ad-hoc.

Comment: @fluffy: Did you read the first pair of snippets? It says nothing about *hardcoding*.

Comment: Yes, I did. There is `Type type = new TypeToken<Master<Child>>() {}.getType();` in your solution no. 1.

Comment: What you describe now, it's not definetly "*hardcoding child classes ad-hoc*" as you have said. That happens in the 2nd solution. You cannot populate the generic type through `Master` without specifying it. Or I don't know the way to do so... if you have that *perfect* solution, I am more than happy to learn and ready to upvote it :)

Comment: There is a way of getting rid of type tokens here at all, hence no ad-hoc `Child` anywhere right there on deserialization. People often miss the point that Gson has no clue on how subclasses can be deserialized without providing extra information (and you're pointing it). The OP is half-way away from the solution: their `Parent` class has the `type` property that remains unused, but it also might give a hint on this.

Comment: There are two known to me ways of deserializing such JSON documents in Gson: either by implementing a sophisticated class structure heuristic deserializer, or using `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java . The latter uses type tags baked right into JSON documents, and that is very similar to what the OP has in their `Parent` class.

Comment: (deleted the previous no-longer-editable comment with a stringified JSON) The latter way is also much easier and faster to use, and having it introduced would have the following JSON `{"id":2,"generic":{"t":{"type":"Child","name":"I am child"}}}` survive the perfect serialization-deserialization round-trip.

Comment: Please, provide an answer. I'd like to run the snippet to see. I have no idea to implement it when the polymorfic generic field is not at the `Master` level but inside the class.

Comment: Please find a round-trip solution at https://pastebin.com/fXL4r1s9

Comment: Looks good to me. You have to, however, remove field `type` declared from `Parent`. Thanks. I have learned somthing new. Feel free to add the answer.

Comment: Don't forget to specify that additional `org.danilopianini:gson-extras` dependency is required.

Comment: This question should probably be closed as a duplicate as `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory`-related stuff was asked million times at StackOverflow, so I don't see a reason of putting an answer. Regarding the artifact grouped as `org.danilopianini`: the `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` is just not bundled as a part of the Gson distribution, and the Gson maintainers recommend simply copy/paste the source code to your codebase and adapt if necessary. The artifact you mentioned is someone else's attempt to supply the class via the artifactory. I'd copy/paste for safety.